# GCC 4.7 fails to inline with message "function body not available"

Tags: gcc

I am trying to compile some legacy code with more modern toolchains. I have tracked down one of my issues to the switch from gcc 4.6 to gcc 4.7:

Some of the functions are annotated with the `inline` keyword. Gcc fails on these with the error message:

```
error: inlining failed in call to always_inline 'get_value_global': function body not available
```

What is the correct way of dealing with this issue? How could the function body not be available? Should the compiler not make sure that it is available in all situations that require it?

---

**Edit**

As requested (in a deleted comment), an example of a signature of a function resulting in the error:

```
inline struct a_value_fmt const *find_a_value_format(struct base_fmt *base)
{
    /* the code */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That error is typical to `inline` functions declared in source files, rather than in header files, in which case the compiler is not able to inline them (as the code of the function to be inlined must be visible to the compiler in the same source file being compiled).  So, first thing I would check is that all functions declared `inline` are indeed defined in header files.

It may be that a change in GCC diagnostics in 4.7 caused the error to surface, and that it went silent in GCC 4.6 (but that's just a speculation).

The quoted error indicates that the function is declared with `__attribute__((always_inline))`. Note that GCC may fail to inline and report a different (and quite obscure) error if function is declared `always_inline`, but not with the `inline` keyword - so make sure that any function declared as `always_inline` is also declared as `inline`.

Few more tips:

- General advice, which may not be applicable: since this is a legacy codebase, you may want to re-evaluate which functions should be inlined, being on the critical path, and which aren't, based on updated profiling results. Sometimes, `inline` is used generously, even when it is not required, or redundant. In some cases, the fix may be to remove the `inline` keyword in places where it is not needed.
- When functions are declared in header files, the compiler considers them for inlining automatically (given they are small enough, and the compiler thinks that inlining them will improve performance, based on its heuristics) - even when the `inline` keyword is not used. `inline` is sort of a "recommendation" to the compiler, and it doesn't have to obey (unless it is given along with the `always_inline` attribute).
- Modern compilers make relatively smart inlining decisions, so it's usually best to let the compiler do it's thing, and declare functions as `inline` (and moving their implementations to header files) in the appliation hot spots, based on profiling results.